# Mongodb intermittently not inserting

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoskin

I am starting out with node.js and mongodb and have created a small test application that is supposed to insert the payload of an incoming UDP packet into mongodb. I am running it on OS X 10.8.4 with `mongodb @2.4.5_0 (active)` installed via MacPorts.

`stack.coffee`

```
dgram = require 'dgram'
mongo = require 'mongoskin'

dbopts =  database: 'stacktest', safe: true, vvv:true
db = mongo.db('mongo://localhost/?auto_reconnect=true', dbopts)
db.bind('foo') 

server = dgram.createSocket('udp4')
server.on "message", (buffer, rinfo) ->
    res = db.foo.insert(buffer.toString(), (err) -> if err? then console.log(err) )

server.on "listening", ->
  address = server.address()
  console.log("UDP server listening " +
      address.address + ":" + address.port)

# listen for UDP packets on port 30000 
server.bind(30000)
```

Running this code with `coffee stack.coffee` and sending it a message from another terminal `echo "Hello"  | nc -w 1 -u localhost  30000` works ok and using `mongo` you will see the message saved:

```
   > use stacktest
   switched to db stacktest
   > db.foo.find()
   { "_id" : ObjectId("520b09cc43ce0ade3601fa0a"), "0" : "H", "1" : "e", "2" : "l", "3" : "l", "4" : "o", "5" : "\n" }
```

But, on a few occasions, and seemingly randomly, the inserts would fail silently. The message comes in, gets picked up by above code but the packets never show (I tested with a small script that sent timestamps). On a new session it would properly save take two, maybe four packets and then silently stop working (i.e. the `err` callback never got called, either). Restarting into a new session *might* fix it, but not always.

Note that I am using safe: true as `dbopts`, so I think I should have been notified on actual errors.

Worst of all it now seems to have fixed itself without any apparent reasons, which adds to the confusion and concern how I would loose inserts.

Any ideas or pointers? Thanks!

Comment: maybe the connection to the DB is dropped? (auto_reconnect doesn't recover automatically from errors)

Comment: Wouldn't that result in some error with code I have? Or if not, what checking would I need to do?